# PHP Version Issue

Tags: php, version, staging

My website is in CORE PHP, I have copied onto other server, same files and imported the DB, even though changed the configuration; but don't know why the same code gives me an error

> Strict Standards: Non-static method DB::connect() should not be called
>   statically in

If I resolve the issue, the issue will generate onto next line. Large numbers of same error shows me on page.

I am doubted on PHP Version
the running website has PHP VERSION is 5.2.17 while the staging server has 5.5.37.

Comment: I think  the error message is pretty clear in telling you what's wrong

Comment: I would suggest not calling the connect method statically :)

Comment: If you cant update the code, you need to run php version <=5.3

Comment: It looks like your hosting company has `E_STRICT` set in the `php.ini` file, but your test server does not. Always set your php.ini to match the destination site before developing. Its quite likely that you will not be able to change that even if you try unsetting it in code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either remove `E_STRICT` from `error_reporting()`, or you can simply make your method static, if you need to call it statically.

**Also, Calling non-static functions in a static context are now deprecated as of PHP 5.6, and the functionality will be removed altogether in a future version, so better to use latest version**

Comment: Thankyou for your reply, It works. I made method statically.

Comment: My rep is less than 15 that's why i could't rate your answer.Though I accepted your ans.